# Compilation error: "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" Unsure why

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation

```
//header
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    //v_number
    double v_number;
    v_number = 255.0;

    //v_percent, v_result
    double v_percent = 0.10;
    double v_result();

    //math
    v_percent * v_number = v_result;
}
//expected output: 10% of 255: 25.5
```

Result:
*main.cpp:15:28: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment*

Apologies that this has been asked before

Comment: `double v_result();` actually declares a function with no arguments that returns a double. Do `double v_result{};` instead. Your error is because you have a temporary on the lhs of the assignment. What exactly are you assigning to?

Comment: What's your intent by doing `v_percent * v_number = v_result`? What variable are you trying to assign to?

Answer (score 0):

if `double v_result();` is your function call you don't need to have "double" in front of `v_result();`.

by having `double v_result()` you are re-declaring the function.

I think what you're trying to do is create a function that just multiples 2 number.
If you want a simple function to multiply 2 number you can just make `v_result()` be a function that take 2 parameters. i.e.

//outside main

`double v_result(double value, double percent)
{
    return (value * percent);
}`

//then inside main() call your function

`std::cout << v_result(v_number,v_percent);`

for the values of v_number and v_percent you defined in main()